# opening website when redirecting to IP using A records

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have created a website in Windows Azure..deployed it properly and configured custom domain for them . Every thing is working fine except when i am opening the website without www prefix it is showing problem.

Earlier i have not added A record in my DNS. I added it and in that A record i put the IP that is the public IP.

But now when i am opening the website without www it is redirecting to that ip but it shows page not found.

when i open using www my website opens.

my website is www.dreamsuccess.in

Its public ip is 137.117.224.218

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the name without www(e.g. dreamsuccess.in) in the A record.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1201235.aspx?Web+site+does+not+open+without+www+prefix
This may be helpfull.

Comment: yes i have added a A record without www , but when it redirect to the IP , since it is and Azure Public IP, it says 404 page not found.is there any way to bind 8080 port automatically in azure websites

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *two* custom domains for your website in Windows Azure. You already added `www.dreamsuccess.in`, now you need to add `dreamsuccess.in` the same way, except this time you will use the A record that Microsoft gives you in your DNS instead of the CNAME. You also have to set up the special `averify` record for it.